# Qt5 Dependency Resolution problem during yum update in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies, qt

I'm getting a dependency resolution error when updating my system. Most Qt5 dependencies are resolved by enabling `epel-testing` however this one remains:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kf5-kdeclarative-5.36.0-2.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
           Requires: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.6.2
           Removing: qt5-qtbase-5.6.2-1.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.6.2-1.el7
           Updated By: qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.9.2-3.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error states: there is a package, `kf5-kdeclarative-5.36.0-2.el7.x86_64 (@epel)`, with a hard dependency, `Requires: qt5-qtbase(x86-64) = 5.6.2` yet your YUM transaction is updating `qt5-qtbase`:  `Updated By: qt5-qtbase-5.9.2-3.el7.x86_64 (base)`.

From here, you have a couple options.  One would be to not update `qt5-qtbase` to the newest version, you can do this using after installing `yum-plugin-versionlock`:

```
yum versionlock qt5-qtbase
```

You could also update `kf5-kdeclarative` to a version that works with `qt5-qtbase-5.9.2`.  I was unable to locate that package in the EPEL repositories so not sure where you could find an update.

You could remove `kf5-kdeclarative` so that `qt5-qtbase` updates cleanly.